# Partitioning a Symfony2 application into subdomains

Tags: php, symfony

I am building a symfony2 application, and I want to split the functionality into two "sites", for example:

- www.mydomain.com       (basic website)
- foobar.mydomain.com    (restricted portion of site, providing specific functionality)

**[Clarification]**

I have already read the documentation pointed out by others below, but Symfony is throwing an exception, with the following error message :

> The parameter "domain" must be defined (500 Internal Server Error)

This is what I have done so far:

1. added foobar.localhost to my /etc/hosts file
2. Modified by routing.yml (see below)
3. Restarted Apache

My routing.yml file looks like this

```
foobar_homepage:
    path:     /
    host:     "foobar.{domain}"
    defaults:
        _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:foobarHomepage
        domain: "%domain%"
    requirements:
        domain: "%domain%"

homepage:
    path:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:homepage }
```

I don't want to hardcode the domain name - so I can use the same codebase and configuration, for multiple sites.

I already have the domain name in the request object. The problem is that its's not clear how to pass that parameter to the route.

So how can I pass the domain name in a **DRY** fashion, in order to satisfy the route requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want fully dynamic host parsing in route without any hardcoded value you should omit default value and requirements for your route. It should look like that:

```
foobar_homepage:
    path:     /
    host:     "foobar.{domain}"
    defaults:
        _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:foobarHomepage
```

Comment: I just worked this out last night. I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem the route matching? If yes, take a look at the symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

You can even make dynamic subdomains. This is a nice video tutorial about it:
http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/symfony2-dynamic-subdomains

Comment: This is similar to what Im trying to do, but in the video, she hard codes the `base_name` variable in the parameters file. I want to have dynamic host names, by inspecting the request object at runtime. Probem is, I can't figure out how to pass the obtained hostname to the route/controller.